# How can I Have Cherry Py redirect a browser to a website?

Tags: python, cherrypy

I was trying to make a Cherry Py page that would redirect the client to a certain site on a certain day of the week. I tried doing `webbrowser.open('sitename.com')` but that simply opened the website in the console. Is there a way you can have it redirect? Note:This is hosted on a Linux box I have offsite and not client side. All help is appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It has been a while since I played with CherryPy, but I think the following should work:

```
raise cherrypy.HTTPRedirect("www.newsite.com")
```

Answer (score 1):

@EricS answer is totally right and works, but you need to pay attention that it will default to a 303 http error code. If you need a 301 or 302 you need to do the following:

```
raise cherrypy.HTTPRedirect("www.newsite.com", status=301)
```